# How do you conditionally execute something when overwriting super while still returning super?

Tags: ruby, subclass, superclass

How do you conditionally execute something when overwriting super, while still returning the result of super? I am sure there is a cleaner way of writing this in Ruby

```
def my_method
  result = super
  if result.success?
    my_other_method1
    my_other_method2
    if @my_field
      @x = @y
    end
  end

  result
end
```

I believe something can be done with block, but don't really understand them yet. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ruby 1.9, you could use the `Object#tap` method to clean that up a bit.

```
def my_method
    super.tap do |result|
        if result.success?
            my_other_method1
            my_other_method2
            if @my_field
                @x = @y
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
def my_method
  super || my_other_method
end
```

Comment: OK great... perhaps I should have elaborated the example. What about when its a lot more than 1 method?  Editing example now

Comment: Wrap it all around a single method.

Comment: Doesn't that only work if result is a boolean? What if result is a complex object? Doesn't my_method then return my_other_method or'ed with the result of super instead of just the result of super?

Comment: There are too many ifs here :) There is no direct simple Ruby solution other than writing the code to do it, unfortunately.